# Object oriented design resources

Tags: oop, ooad

I am looking for good resources (books/web sites) for learning object oriented design. Every resource that I find are tutoring me more on UML and RUP instead of OO design. Head first book's sheer repetition is making me not want to read any of their books. I am looking for a book similar to "[Structure and interpretation of computer programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/)" for object oriented design that gets to the point of teaching OO. I have no preference for any specific OO laguage.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the Head First Design Patterns Book, or the OA & D one...

Comment: I love this thread :)

Comment: You need a course where you can get practice designing objects the right way. A book is not going to allow that. Take this course on Object Oriented Design HW + Solutions: https://www.udemy.com/mastering-object-oriented-design-in-java/?couponCode=newyearsale

Answer (score 6):

[Object-Oriented Analysis and Design with Applications](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805353402) by Grady Booch is the bible for this topic.  It is also very approachable though somewhat dense at points, but definitely worth reading and re-reading.

Comment: I loved that book, and personally I didn't find it dense at any point.

Answer (score 2):

Also as replacement for the Gang of Four book.

I can recommend: [The Design Patterns Smalltalk Companion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201184621)

In general learning Smalltalk will help you to be a better OOP Developer on any language.

From the Amazon reviews:

> Easier to understand than the original
>   GoF, February 4, 2000 By  Nicolas
>   Weidmann 
>  This
>   book gives you a better understanding
>   of the patterns than in its original
>   version (the GoF one). I am not a
>   SmallTalk programmer but a 9 years C++
>   one. At work I had to use the GoF book
>   and never liked reading it. In
>   contrast to this, the SmallTalk
>   companion is easy to read and you can
>   understand the patterns within the
>   first few lines of their description.
>   Take the Bridge pattern and compare
>   their discussions in the two books. If
>   you really like the Gof one then buy
>   it. But according to me, it would be a
>   big mistake buying the GoF in favour
>   of the SmallTalk companion. Trust a
>   C++ programmer :-)

Comment: Gang of Four should not be the first book to read in OOP.It's more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that the *Head First Design Pattern* is really a nice book but the famous *Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software* is still a must read too.

On the web, the [What Is Object-Oriented Design?](http://www.objectmentor.com/omSolutions/oops_what.html) page of the Object Mentor website is another great resource.

Comment: There is a Head First book for Object Oriented design and analysis, it's worth a read even if you are an experienced OO developer.

Comment: So far, I liked all books of the Head First series I've read. So I'll check this one too. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting myself from another answer on the same topic:

> Great resources to learn how to think
>   in patterns and do correct OOP
>   analysis and design are [Analysis
>   Patterns: Reusable Object Models](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201895420)
>   by Martin Fowler and [Applying UML and
>   Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137488807) by Craig Larman. Also I
>   need to mention here [Domain-Driven
>   Design: Tackling Complexity in the
>   Heart of Software](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) by Eric Evans,
>   the most valuable book I found to
>   think about the whole software design
>   process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [paper](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/spring2003/cmsc838p/Design/criteria.pdf) by D.L. Parnas, especially the "The Criteria" section. Only six pages and so much truth and wisdom in there.

Answer (score 1):

You need a course where you can get practice designing objects the right way. A book is not going to allow that. Take a course from Job Ready Programmer. This site has practical real world projects to add to your resume. A good course that covers the SOLID OOP Principles and popular design patterns is: Object Oriented Design HW + Solutions: https://www.jobreadyprogrammer.com

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read but have heard really good things of: [Object-Oriented Design Heuristics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/020163385X) by Arthur J. Riel.

A typical amazon review of the book:

> If you're experienced with language-specifics, and ready to get a grasp on 
>   the better ways to implement your designs so that they are more maintainable and logical,
>   then grab this text.

Answer (score 0):

For examples of good OO Designs 
You can look at:

[Holub on Patterns: Learning Design Patterns by Looking at Code](http://www.apress.com/book/view/9781590593882)